# UWP Application Screen Saver

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml, windows-10-iot-core

I developed a UWP application and I am using windows Iot and RP3 and 7" official hdmi touche screen.

I am trying to get the screen saver or screen to go on or to simply black out the screen.

I did look at the class called "DisplayRequest Class" but not sure if that is correct?

Any help would be great.

Thanks
Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows IoT Core does support screen saver like Windows 10, even DisplayRequest class can work on Windows IoT Core. You may implement a custom page as screen saver in your UWP app.Please refer to the [Screensaver](https://github.com/ms-iot/samples/blob/240516f02e69c5773967b1f6991ce6bc033ebe68/IoTCoreDefaultApp/IoTCoreDefaultApp/Views/Screensaver.xaml.cs) class in IoTCoreDefaultApp.